# Extremely unhelpful error messages... Can't create function

Tags: mysql, function

I've just started to learn how to create functions in SQL and so I'm trying to make a simple one that 'converts' datetime to text "day month_name year" but I got stuck because there's an error I can't figure out as the error message simply says "There is an error in your syntax" and points to first declare. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION 'testf'(invar DATETIME) RETURNS varchar(15)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vout varchar(30);
    DECLARE vin varchar(15);

    set vin = extract(month from invar);

    case vin
        when 1 then set vout = 'Styczeń';
        when 2 then set vout = 'Luty';
        when 3 then set vout = 'Marzec';
        when 4 then set vout = 'Kwiecień';
        when 5 then set vout = 'Maj';
        when 6 then set vout = 'Czerwiec';
        when 7 then set vout = 'Lipiec';
        when 8 then set vout = 'Sierpień';
        when 9 then set vout = 'Wrzesień';
        when 10 then set vout = 'Październik';
        when 11 then set vout = 'Listopad';
        when 12 then set vout = 'Grudzień';
    end case;

    return concat(
        extract(day from invar),
        ' ',
        vout,
        ' ',
        extract(year from invar)
    );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around the function name. Every example you can find doesn't have these quotes - it's effectively a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the simple quotes in the function name.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION testf(invar DATETIME) RETURNS varchar(15)
BEGIN
   DECLARE vout varchar(30);
   DECLARE vin varchar(15);

   set vin = extract(month from invar);

   case vin
       when 1 then set vout = 'Styczeń';
       when 2 then set vout = 'Luty';
       when 3 then set vout = 'Marzec';
       when 4 then set vout = 'Kwiecień';
       when 5 then set vout = 'Maj';
       when 6 then set vout = 'Czerwiec';
       when 7 then set vout = 'Lipiec';
       when 8 then set vout = 'Sierpień';
       when 9 then set vout = 'Wrzesień';
       when 10 then set vout = 'Październik';
       when 11 then set vout = 'Listopad';
       when 12 then set vout = 'Grudzień';
   end case;

   return concat(
       extract(day from invar),
       ' ',
       vout,
       ' ',
       extract(year from invar)
   );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I've tested it without the quotes and the function is created successfully.

Comment: So simple yet I didn't notice it by myself...Thank you

Comment: @Miku No problem. Glad to help. It can happen to anyone. As we say in Spain: today for you, tomorrow for me. :-)